# Using .wrap() function

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to edit the code of some images of my website in the next way:
For example, I have:

```
<div id="slideshowContainer473">
<img src="src_image1" alt="image1" title="image1" />
<img src="src_image2" alt="image2" title="image2" />
<img src="src_image3" alt="image3" title="image3" />
</div>
```

What I want, for each image, is to obtain:

```
<a href="src_image1" rel="lightbox"><img src="src_image1" alt="image1" title="image1" /></a>
```

That is, through jquery, **gives to href the same value than src** and I also need add rel="lightbox" because I think to use http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/

I think I can obtain it, using .wrap()
I think .each() is also needed, right?

Comment: If you know all this already ... what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("div#slideshowContainer473 img").wrap(function(){
    return "<a href=\"" + this.src + "\" rel=\"lightbox\" />";
});
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Once you get used to callback functions in methods like `.wrap` and `.html` you learn to assume they're everywhere in jQuery -- and they usually are.

Comment: Incidentally, using `this.src` returns a full URL (at least in Chrome) while `$(this).attr('src')` returns the exact string used in the HTML. The end result is the same to the user, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('img').wrap(function() {
    return $('<a>', {
        src: $(this).attr('src'),
        rel: 'lightbox'
    })
})​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ktvpA/1/)**